# How to set webpack uglifyoptions in vue cli to mantain comments?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I need to configure Uglify options in a vue cli project.

What I need is to mantain certain comments, so I've tried to set up this in vue cli, without success.

```
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: /\<\/?fs_premium_only\>/i
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  },
```

Is something I'm doing wrong? if I inspect the vue config I see that the options is there, but my comment are stripped out.

Is there any way to preserve those comments?

Answer (score 0):

It came ot I must use this syntax:

```
  chainWebpack: config => config.optimization.minimizer([new UglifyJsPlugin({
    uglifyOptions: {
      output: {
        comments: /\<\/?fs_premium_only\>/i,
      }
    }   
  })])
```